# Why '$' in regex isn't working as expected in debian?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have the following file:

`cat regex16.txt` gives

```
    foo bar baz
    bar foo baz
    baz foo bar
    bar baz foo
    foo baz bar
    baz bar foo
```

I want to `grep` only the lines which end with `bar`.

So, I am using `$` symbol to `grep` for `bar`. But, I don't get any results. What am I doing wrong here?

```
grep '.*bar$' regex16.txt
```

Why `bar$` isn't working here?

Comment: Use `cat -A` and see if you have spaces or something at the end of those lines.

Comment: Was an MS-Windows or Dos system involved at any point?

Comment: The `.*` is redundant.